# Multiple Timers in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated

How to deal with multiple timers/countdowns in `React Native`? I have about 10-20 timers, so the `JS Thread` can block, and also the `JS fps` jumps every second. How can I run it in another thread or in worklets? I could not to use `react-native-reanimated` or `react-native-worklets-core`.

My countdown hook:

```
export const useCountdown = (deadline: string): number => {
    const countDownDate = useMemo(() => Date.parse(deadline), [deadline]);
    const [countDown, setCountDown] = useState(countDownDate - new Date().getTime());

    useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(() => {
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                // countDownDate - new Date().getTime()
                setCountDown((prev) => prev - 1000);
            }, 1000);

            return () => {
                clearInterval(interval);
            };
        }, []),
    );

    return countDown;
};
```

Timer:

```
interface TimerProps {
    deadline: Dayjs;
}

export const Timer: React.FC<TimerProps> = ({ deadline }) => {
    const countDown = useCountdown(deadline);

    if (countDown <= 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{millisecondsToCountTime(countDown)}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    gap: {
        gap: scale.ss,
    },
});
```